# How do I index HDFS files in solr?

Tags: hadoop, solr, hdfs

I have text files in hadoop which needs to be indexed using solr. How do I proceed?

I want to read the files from hdfs://localhost:54310/files/ directory.

Is there a simple shell command for that?

PS: I have set the data directory of solr to hadoop.